# WatchKit Interface controller scrolls too much after adding next page segue

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, interface-builder, watchkit, apple-watch

experts!

Today started to build Apple Watch version for my CelebrateMore! app and can't solve one issue. I have 2 interface controllers - Page-based kind. As soon as I set segue to "next page" from first to second, my first interface controller starts to scroll much more than before.

Screenshot from Storyboard:
[image: Screenshot from Storyboard:]

Screenshot from simulator during scrolling:

[image: Scrolling issue]

Screenshot from simulator if I remove next page segue and scroll:

[image]

Already from scrollbar it can be seen, that there is a lot of empty content if "next page" is used. Does anyone has some idea, how to solve this, how to avoid "the long after content scrolling" issue?

Comment: I am hoping this is a bug. It seems to make the height of the initial controller ridiculously large when you add a next page segue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've struggled with the same issue for several hours until I decided to give it up for a while and focus on filling the labels with actual data at runtime. After I added some code to the main initialisation methods of `WKInterfaceController` (`(void)awakeWithContext:(id)context {}` and/or `(void)willActivate {}` ), this scrolling issue magically disappeared. Try to set the text of one or all the labels in your interface in code in one of the 2 methods mentioned above and see if the scrolling problem gets fixed:

```
[self.label setText:@"Some text.."];
```

It worked in my case.

Comment: I didn't even have a label on my controller (just a single button), but adding a dummy text to the bottom of the button and then adding the above code, I was able to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Due to low reputation I cannot upvote: The solution of setting the text of a label worked for me too. I set an empty text first, then load the data and update the label there again once the request is successful. It works and calculates the height of the scroll view correctly.

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    //enable correct scroll height
    self.titleLabel.setText("")

    self.loadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a different way to work around it.

First put a group in the InterfaceController, and assign fixed height to it, then put other components inside the group.

To make the group occupy full screen, its height for 38mm should be set to about 142 point and for 42mm should be set to about 165 point. You can use the plus sign next to the value to enter these values for the 2 models.

Comment: Or you could use `Relative to Container` and set the value of the input below the select to `1`.

Comment: No, that didn't work for me. That was the bug - the root container height  of the first screen in a page-based hierarchy was somehow set to a large value, and I had to use the group to give it a correct and fixed height. But then maybe this has been fixed in the latest version, I haven't tried lately.

Comment: I understand. But, are you sure the numbers are correct? [This article](http://www.macrumors.com/2014/11/18/apple-watch-resolutions) tells something else.

Comment: Perhaps it was because the "full screen" I mentioned doesn't include the status bar on top.